# Java, add a value to list<pair>

Tags: java, list, class, collections, insert

I'm struggling with getting a value from `List<Integer>` to `List<Pair<Integer,Integer>>`. Pair is a class written by me which I enclose. 
Any ideas how to do it? I would prefer to make a deep copy instead of copying just references. I believe that getting a value from list works fine, the problem is with inserting this value to listPair.

I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

```
public class Pair<L,R>{
    private L key;
    private R value;


    public Pair(L key, R value)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public L getL() {return key;}
    public R getR() {return value;}
    public void setL(L key) {this.key = key;}
    public void setR(R value) {this.value = value;}
}

It's how I create list(in main()) which I send to function createMatrix
List<Integer> numbersCopy = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void createMatrix(List<Integer> list,List<List<Pair<Integer,Integer>>> matrix)
    {       
        Collections.sort(list); //sortuje listę
        Collections.reverse(list); //odwraca kolejnosc
        int key = 0;
        List<Pair<Integer,Integer>> listPair = new ArrayList<Pair<Integer,Integer>>();
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            listPair.setR(i) = list.get(i); //elements of list should be saved to value in Pair<Integer, Integer>
        }

}
```

Comment: Try: `listPair.add(new Pair(i, list.get(i)))`

Comment: What do you expect to be in the first half of the pair?  And why do you think you need a deep copy when integers are immutable?  And why did you make your Pair class mutable?

Comment: I wanted a deep copy because I'm making a graph with values from list<Integer> and I will be deleting values and changing them. I am new to Java and though that it will affect values in list<Pair<Integer,Integer>> if I copy just references. And I don't know what does it mean that Pair class is mutable.

Comment: What is more I tried both methods and none of them is working properly. When using Titus's solutino I receive Note: czyGraficzny.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Comment: Why don't you use a simple map? a List of "pairs" (which not even have the same type) is nothing oters than a map (with the Map.Entry element).

Answer (score 1):

Change your `createMatrix` method to below

```
public static void createMatrix(List<Integer> list, List<List<Pair<Integer, Integer>>> matrix) {
    List<Integer> numbersCopy = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Collections.sort(list); //sortuje listę
    Collections.reverse(list); //odwraca kolejnosc
    int key = 0;
    List<Pair<Integer,Integer>> listPair = new ArrayList<Pair<Integer,Integer>>();
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    {
        listPair.add(new Pair<Integer, Integer>(i, list.get(i))); //elements of list should be saved to value in Pair<Integer, Integer>
    }
}
```

Modified Line in the code is `listPair.add(new Pair<Integer, Integer>(i, list.get(i)));`

Answer (score 0):

For me it look like a `Map.Entry<K,V>` is the implementation you look for than you can just call the `put(K key, V value)` function.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Answer (score 0):

I think more simple is create a Bean with 2 inner fields and put it as

```
class MyBean{
Integer int0 =null;
Integer int1 =null;
}
List<MyBean> datos = new List<MyBean>();
```